# Fixing Autonumber Issue

Tags: apex, auto-number

I have an object X which has Standard Name field as autonumber. There are about 10000 records in tht object. Upon checking found out that out of 10000, only 600 records are in autonumber, rest all are in aribitary text. Not sure how it happened. Now need to fix it.

I want to fix it like the oldest record should start from A-00000 and the sequence will go on and the last record should end with A-10000.

How to achieve this.

Regards

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to go to the custom object, change the Name field to be a Text type, export all the records, update the Name values, import the new data, then change it back to an Auto-Number field. If possible, I recommend that you change the object to "In Development" so that users can't modify the data while you're working on this.